# Edittext data appears in other edittext scrolling in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm a newbie coding witch android studio and I try to save data on editText inside a recyclerview but data disappear or is duplicated in another editText.

Could someone help me please ?

Here is my code :

TaskActivity.java

```
    package com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.opengl.EGLDisplay;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.R;
import com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.classes.ReturnResponse;
import com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.classes.Task;
import com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.classes.TaskAdapter;
import com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.classes.TaskToSend;
import com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.classes.User;
import com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.services.JsonService;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import static android.R.attr.button;
import static android.R.attr.title;

public class TasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public TaskAdapter mAdapter;
    Button GoPhoto;
    String user;

    JsonService service;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);
        Button uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butUpload);
        GoPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt_photo);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getString(R.string.base_url))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(JsonService.class);
        Button takePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt_photo);
        user = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
        //imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                TaskToSend task;
                List<TaskToSend> listTask = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {

                    task = new TaskToSend(mAdapter.getItem(i).getTitle(), String.valueOf(mAdapter.getItem(i).isState()), mAdapter.getItem(i).getComment(), user);

                    if (task.getState() == "true") {
                        task.setState("Fait");
                    } else {
                        task.setState("Non fait");
                    }

                    listTask.add(task);

                }

                service.saveTasks(listTask).enqueue(new Callback<ReturnResponse>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ReturnResponse> call, Response<ReturnResponse> response) {
                        Log.wtf("Fichier", "Réponse");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ReturnResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.wtf("Fichier", "Pas de réponse");
                    }
                });
                Intent TakstoUpload = new Intent(TasksActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
                startActivity(TakstoUpload);
            }
        });

        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
           }
        });




        service.getTasks().enqueue(new Callback<List<Task>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Task>> call, Response<List<Task>> response) {

                List<Task> listeTaches = response.body();
                Log.wtf("Nombre de taches", "Nombre de taches : " + listeTaches.size());
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int DayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                for (Task t : listeTaches) {
                     if (t.getPeriod()== DayOfWeek || t.getPeriod()== 0) {
                        taskList.add(t);
                    }
                }
                displayRecyclerView();
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.wtf("GetTasks Failure", t.toString());
            }
        });


        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    public void displayRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tasks_recycler_view);
        mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(taskList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }


    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Tasks Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        }

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Here my adapter TaskAdapter :

```
package com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.classes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.R;
import com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.activities.TasksActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.data;
import static android.R.attr.value;
import static com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.R.id.checkBox;

/**
 * Created by David SIMON on 22/08/2016.
 */
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private List<Task> TaskList;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public CheckBox checkBox;
        public EditText finalComment;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            finalComment = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.FinalComment);
            TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    int position = (int) finalComment.getTag();
                    TaskList.get(position).setComment(charSequence.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


                }
            };
            finalComment.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        }
    }


    public TaskAdapter(List<Task> TaskList) {

        this.TaskList = TaskList;
    }



    @Override
    public TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyvlerview, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {



        Task task = TaskList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(task.getTitle());
        holder.finalComment.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(task.isState());

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                task.setState(b);
            }
        });

    }


    public Task getItem(int position){
        return TaskList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return TaskList.size();
    }


}
```

And my Task.java

```
package com.example.davidsimon.appexploit.classes;

/**
 * Created by David SIMON on 05/08/2016.
 */
public class Task {

    String title;
    boolean state;
    String comment;
    int period;
    String type;

    public Task(String title, boolean state, String comment, String type, int period) {
        this.title = title;
        this.state = state;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.type = type;
        this.period = period;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Title : "+ title +
                "\nState : " + state +
                "\nComment : " + comment +
                "\nPeriod : " + period +
                "\nType : " + type;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public boolean isState() {
        return state;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getPeriod() { return period; }

    public void setPeriod(int period) { this.period = period; }
}
```

I just want to save data in my EditText "finalcomment". I already search some similar problem but I think my level is too low.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should take a class, or find a really good friend, or offer to pay someone to individually tutor you? That's a LOT of code to have stranger volunteer here to study just to help you debug your vague unfocused problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RecyclerView will reuse your views. So whenever you scroll `onBindViewHolder` will be called. Within that method you need to setup the view with the correct data. You need to set the EditText in your onBindViewHolder which will likely require you to save the tex that has been entered. Here's an example of how you'd do that without the save logic:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {



    Task task = TaskList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(task.getTitle());
    holder.finalComment.setTag(position);

    // You need to save the entered text and then set it in onBindViewHolder
    holder.finalComment.setText(THE TEXT FOR THE EDIT TEXT);

    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(task.isState());

    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            task.setState(b);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: It seems to be good, I added         holder.finalComment.setText(TaskList.get(position).getComment());
inside the onBindviewholder
I'll test that in production :)
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in recycling views.
Your RecyclerView reuse views that exited from the screen for other object, to save time and memory.

So what you need is to always set all desired data into onBindViewHolder method. Otherwise if a view exit from the visible screen and it is reused, it will be reused with old data.

Using EditText into RecyclerView is not a good decision, because you are mixing user inputs with presentation data.
If you want to keep this approach, you must find a way to save data associated to each RecyclerView item, to be then always able to set them to the right recycled view when it becomes again visible.

Obviously you need also to keep information of empty views.

Hope I have clarified enough

Answer (score 0):

I seen a problem, if my solution doesn't work then let me know!
Inside your `TaskAdapter` class, `onBindViewHolder()` method:

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

```
    Task task = TaskList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(task.getTitle());
    //this one is wrong
    //holder.finalComment.setTag(position);
    //while doing this you will get the text of final comment in your 
    //edit text of final comment
    holder.finalComment.setText(task.getComment());
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(task.isState());

    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            task.setState(b);
        }
    });

}
```